# Help identify a chicken peruvian (?) dish

Tags: chicken, food-identification

In 2019 a dish was served to me (in the Iquitos area if it helps), which I can't find anywhere, since I don't know it's name. I only remember that it was chicken thighs (maybe also wings), in a brown gravy (it was rather creamy & sticky). My wife says it wasn't sweet or sour, more like salty. Unfortunately I can't remember any more characteristics.

As a side dish - as I later figured it out - there was [arroz árabe](https://silvanapastrychef.wordpress.com/2018/11/29/arroz-arabe-peruvian-style-christmas-arabic-rice/) (without nuts) and plantain chips.

I know it's not much information, but I hope someone can tell me the name of the dish?

Comment: You can often find lists of dishes from a given cuisine on Wikipedia.   In this case, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Peruvian_dishes .  If you speak Spanish, or go through Google translate, you can also try going through the spanish language Wikipedia to see if they have a similar list.

Comment: Do you remember where it was served (restaurant, home...)? and if so, do you remember texture of the sauce beyond sticky - was it sticky like gravy or sticky like syrup?

Comment: It was served in a jungle lodge. The texture was gravy, I was just missing the word. I'll correct the question.

Comment: If you know the lodge, you might be able to find a menu - most of the ones I could see from a quick google seemed to serve a mix of international and local foods.